# What is the name of this little plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image: plant specimen]

It was found in Malaysia in my school compound.

Comment: Looks like something in the mint family.  Does it have an odor?

Comment: May be [*Scoparia dulcis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoparia_dulcis) but I am not sure at all. Do you find a dense hairy structure on its corolla?